# How to simplify the query qualification?

Tags: databases, relational-algebra

Given the following DB and query :
[image]

[image]

Now if we need to simplify the query qualification, here is the answer from the book (Principle of distributed database systems, third edition) :

[image]

My question is in the highlighted bracket, I think this should be (p1 OR (p2 AND (Not p2))) instead of the one written because we have the following rule :

[image]

Is that right ?

Comment: Please use text, not images, for what can be expressed in text. For this post, that's everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, but it doesn't really matter — it still simplifies to $p_1$.